# Transition to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, transition

I have a web app in regular php, witout opp and without mvc structure, so It is very different of laravel but I want to move to laravel.

The thing is that the website it is already and my clients are already using it a lot, how should I make the transition? the thing is that I need to start making little changes like making the transition in parts, but I need everything to keep working.

something like rigth know everything is regular php, the it will be regular php (no mvc and no oop) and laravel combine and at the end it is going to be just laravel.

I need to know if that mix of regular php and laravel could be done and how can I make it.

This is because we need to be changing the app a lot, adding some funcionality so if I do it everything in laravel locally,then the current webpage is going to being growing, so I would need to make every new functionality in regular php so it can run in the current page but also in the laravel version, so it is double work and a lot of more time that if I can start changing and when a new funcionality is required I can do it in laravel rigth away.

Comment: You can add it as a separate system beside the old site, route all requests to laravel and route all not found routes in laravel to the old site. Then you can just start migrating one route at a time

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, i totally encourage you to learn OOP and Laravel itself, its actually fairly simple...

The thing is that **Laravel** makes use of this thing called: Convention over Configuration Pattern, which involves the fact that you **KNOW** how a MVC/OOP app works, and by that, makes a really simple environment for the developing, that makes kinda impossible to mix regular/non-OOP PHP with the workflow of the framework and so on...

Trust me, once you learn how to use laravel (which is **REALLY** simple :) ) everything will fall in order.

These links will help you to reach your goal:

- **[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/)**: provides you a really good screen cast, to learn through videos about OOP and Laravel (Aswell as other topics as JS, Vue.js and so on...)

I recommend you these two courses:

** https://laracasts.com/series/object-oriented-bootcamp-in-php

** https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Also, the official docs:

- **[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4)**: It will guide you to understand the way the framework works.

Comment: OP already wants to learn Laravel. IMO, this misses the point of the question - how to add Laravel to an already active site in parts.

Comment: I already know laravel, I learned with those course so that it is no the problem the problem is what @ceejayoz said. " how to add Laravel to an already active site in parts.".

maybe I did nor make myself clear.

Comment: Oh, It looks like I've misunderstood your statement... In that order @JimL comment makes sense to me.